# Unbound Local Error in function

Tags: python

```
def pingpong(n):
    invisible_number = 0
    return_value = 0
    G = -1
    while invisible_number != n:
        if invisible_number > 10 and invisible_number < 100:
            invisible_number_ones_digit = invisible_number % 10
            invisible_number_tens_digit = invisible_number // 10
            return invisible_number_ones_digit and invisible_number_tens_digit
        if invisible_number > 100 and invisible_number < 1000:
            invisible_number_ones_digit = (invisible_number % 10) % 10
            invisible_number_tens_digit = (invisible_number % 10) // 10
            invisible_number_hundreds_digit = (invisible_number // 10) // 10
            return invisible_number_ones_digit and invisible_number_tens_digit and invisible_number_hundreds_digit
        if invisible_number % 7 == 0:
            return_value = return_value - G
            G = -1 * G

        elif invisible_number_ones_digit == 7 or invisible_number_tens_digit == 7 or invisible_number_hundreds_digit == 7:
            return_value = return_value - G
            G = -1 * G 
        else:
            return_value += G
        invisible_number += 1
    return return_value
```

This is for question number 3 [here](http://cs61a.org/hw/hw03/). I am only trying to get to up to 1000 for containing the digit `7` because I can't seem to find a pattern that I could use.

Comment: Can you please check that your code indentation is correct here?  It looks like everything after the first line should be indented one tab.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full traceback; now we have to guess where the error occurs.

Comment: If the first three conditions are not satisfied, you end up in the `elif` part that uses as yet unassigned variables: `invisible_number_ones_digit`, `invisible_number_tens_digit` and `invisible_number_hundreds_digit`.

Comment: Oh sorry this is my first time using this

Comment: I do not know how to add a full traceback but the error occurs here         elif invisible_number_ones_digit == 7 or invisible_number_tens_digit == 7 or invisible_number_hundreds_digit == 7:                                                        And thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your UnboundLocalError is "local variable 'invisible_number_ones_digit' referenced before assignment". You set

```
invisible_number = 0
```

so if you call `pingpong(n)` where n is anything but 0, your code is going to fail when you reference the value of `invisible_number_ones_digit`, which you're currently doing in the `elif`. Same with any other variables which you are using before you've assigned them a value.